# $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{\langle v - x, x-x_0 \rangle}{||x-x_0||}=?$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, limits

Let $v$ and $x_0$ be fixed points in $\mathbb R^n$,  I don't know how to compute the limit $$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{\langle v - x, x-x_0 \rangle}{||x-x_0||}=?$$
Where $x\in \mathbb R^n$ and $||x-x_0||$ is the Euclidean distance between $x$ and $x_0$, here $x\rightarrow x_0$ means $||x-x_0||\rightarrow 0$. We may further assume that $\langle v - x, x-x_0 \rangle\geq 0$ if needed.

I guess that the limit should be $||v-x_0||$. But how to prove that?

---

**Edit.** Let me add my attempt.

Without loss of generality, we may assume that $x_0=0$, thus
the quantity is equal to $\frac{\langle v, x\rangle}{||x||} -||x||$. We have $x\rightarrow 0$, then $||x||\rightarrow 0$. So the remaining is to find
$$\lim_{||x||\rightarrow 0} \frac{\langle v, x\rangle}{||x||}=?$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $v\neq 0$, there is no limit for

$$ \lim_{||x||\rightarrow 0} \frac{\langle v, x\rangle}{||x||}$$

Since when taking $x = tv$ we have

$$ \frac{\langle v, x\rangle }{\|x\| } = \begin{cases} \|v\| & t >0, \\ -\|v\| & t<0.\end{cases}$$

So the limit does not exist as $t\to 0$.